# cors vue frontend and express backend

Tags: javascript, express, cors, webserver

My frontend `:8080` and my backend `:8081` are running on the same computer `http://192.168.178.20`. If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080` on my computer everything works fine (I can successfully send requests to my backend). When I navigate from my smartphone to `http://192.168.178.20:8080`, the frontend will be displayed as intended. But I can not send requests from my smartphone to the backend, it think it has to do with the cors configuration but I could not figure it out how to change it correctly.

Do I have to whitelist my smartphone in some way on the backend? How does a proper configuration look, when I want to run this in production and not in development mode?

The smartphones private ip address (same network as computer) is `192.168.178.21`.

My current backend configuration looks like this:

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

const SERVER_PORT = 8081;
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ 
  origin: ['http://localhost:8080'], 
  credentials: true 
}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ 
  extended: true 
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});

// my routes ...

app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Backend is listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your smartphone, the origin is `http://192.168.178.20:8080`, but in your CORS configuration you allow only `http://localhost:8080`. Try

```js
app.use(cors({ 
  origin: ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://192.168.178.20:8080'],
  allowedHeaders: 'x-access-token',
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
  credentials: true 
}));
```

and remove the (redundant) middleware that explicitly sets the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers. (`Origin, Content-Type, Accept` need not be set as allowed headers, they are always allowed, unless you mean, e.g., `Content-Type: application/json`.)

The IP address of the client (your smartphone) does not matter, only the address and host of the frontend server.